# Is the DataMember IsRequired attribute in combination with a Nullable type contradictory?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, datamember, isrequired

I came across this today in a WCF contract:

```
[DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
public DateTime? LastModified { get; set; }
```

What are the consequences of `IsRequired = True` and a nullable `DateTime`? They appear to be contradictory to each other.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can make sense if you want to initialize it with null and let user to set a valid date. So before submitting it can validate user input.

Here is a similar contradictory that may answer your question.

[Interaction with IsRequired](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347792.aspx)

> The DataMemberAttribute attribute has an IsRequired property (the
>   default is false). The property indicates whether a given data member
>   must be present in the serialized data when it is being deserialized.
>   If IsRequired is set to true, (which indicates that a value must be
>   present) and EmitDefaultValue is set to false (indicating that the
>   value must not be present if it is set to its default value), default
>   values for this data member cannot be serialized because the results
>   would be contradictory. If such a data member is set to its default
>   value (usually null or zero) and a serialization is attempted, a
>   SerializationException is thrown.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly (or more appropriately - MSDN double-Dutch), a SerializationException would be the result if the value of this property is set to null OR excluded completely. Thus it would be better to exclude the IsRequired property altogether?

Comment: Think about compatibility with older versions of your service. If you want you can make new members IsRequired false and pass a default value in.

Comment: @Junto: I think so, IsRequired false is safer and makes more sense.

Answer (score 3):

A guess: you MUST have a node for 'LastModified' (=required) but the contents can be empty (=value is null).